# PWA GET request strange comportement

Tags: angular, post, caching, progressive-web-apps

in a PWA with Angular, we are experiencing a strange (or not) behavior. When offline with the service worker, we can successfully cache GET requests. We save POST requests in the index DB and execute them when the app comes back online.

Everything is fine, BUT after the executed POST request, all cached GET requests (for the same object) are cleared. So, if your application goes offline immediately after, you cannot use the cache to serve the user. However, making another GET request works fine.

Why are cached GET requests cleared after a POST request?

Is there a mechanism to make a background request for this GET object in order to reload the cache?

We have tried to modify the header and not return a "no-cache" with POST request